# How to add existing sitecore field editors to a page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, sitecore

I'm creating an aspx page that users can use to create an item.
Depending on what template the item is base on the user is presented with a list of labels and a textbox.
( I started off with templates that only contain Single Line Text )

Now I also want a user-friendly way to handle templates that contain images ( or richtext, ... )
I'd like to use the existing sitecore controls to help me add these field types.

But the problem is I cannot seem to find a way to implement these into my page.
I found the class that I would most likely need to use " Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Image ".

My first thought was to created an ascx that would implement this class. However this is not possible as it needs to implement " System.Web.UI.UserControl "
Does anyone know how I can add existing sitecore editor controls to a my page ?

Answer (score 2):

You would be very hard pressed to make these controls work, outside the context they are designed to run in; the Sitecore Content Editor.

In short; the answer is no - you cannot.

What you are trying to do, is part of the reason SPEAK was developed for Sitecore. Depending on your Sitecore version, this is the route you should be looking at.